# How to package older version of a common jar in a library & use a recent version in the war project

Tags: java, maven

I have a strange situation where I need a common jar, which is an older version, in a dependency jar. But the war i'm working on will have a more recent version of the common jar. In my war project pom, i have included the latest one, but the dependency jar should have older version of common jar to support the old access modifiers. All the projects are maven build

```
Dependency jar - 1.0
   - Common jar - 1.0

War App - 2.0
  - Dependency jar - 1.0
      -Common jar - 1.0
  - Common jar - 2.0
```

Comment: You can try to use the maven shade plugin to rename the packages of one version of the `Common jar`, but often it is better to figure out one version that can be used everywhere.

Comment: I agree, but we can risk updating the production version to fix this. It needs to be tested thoroughly because a lot of code is dependent on that common jar in another application.

Comment: So what version did you use in production so far?

Comment: We use  common 1.0 jar in Prod

Comment: So why don't you use version 1.0 also in your War? Otherwise you need to use "tricks" like shading (renaming packages automatically).